# Thinking Sphinx not converting attribute from :decimal to :float in PostGresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Having a bit of trouble with Thinking_Sphinx. To whit:

I have a Restaurant model and a Review Model with the following relationship:

```
Restaurant Has_many Reviews through relationships
Review belongs_to Restaurant through relationships
```

Each review has a rating that is off of a  decimal system, with 0.5 increments.

I search for restaurants in Thinking Sphinx, and set the review rating as an attribute as follows (I do this so the results are ordered in descending order of rating value):

```
has reviews.rating, :as => :review_rating, :type => :float
```

And this is the error I get when I index Thinking Sphinx in the terminal:

```
indexing index 'restaurant_core'...
ERROR: source 'restaurant_core_0': expected attr type ('uint' or 'timestamp' or 'bigint') in sql_attr_multi, got 'float review_rating from field'.
ERROR: index 'restaurant_core': failed to configure some of the sources, will not index.
```

Interesting story: when I change the :type to :integer, as follows:

```
has reviews.rating, :as => :review_rating, :type => :integer
```

I don't get an error.

I am running Ruby on Rails 3.2.11, Thinking Sphinx 3.0.1, Ubuntu 12.10

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that one `Restaurant` has many `Review`s, but you're indexing `reviews.rating` as a single value. You should change your indexing to either calculate some aggregate (e.g. mean, median, highest or lowest) of the reviews, or use a Multi-Valued Attribute (MVA). However, MVAs can only be integers, timestamps or booleans.

For example, to have the mean of the ratings as the attribute value, something like this should work:

```
has "AVG(reviews.rating)", :as => :review_rating, :type => :float
```

Of course, the exact code depends on your table names etc. Check the generated `sphinx.conf` file if you're having trouble.